# GCP Run error finding executable "python" in PATH

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, deployment, fastapi

Hi I'm using GCP Run to deploy my python (fast API) API, I set the entry point to `python -m api` (tried other approaches as well like `usr/local/bin/python`), because that's how I start it (In `__main__.py` i do have Uvicorn set up). But it doesn't work and I get this error:

```
terminated: Application failed to start: kernel init: cannot resolve init executable: error finding executable "python" in PATH [/usr/local/sbin /usr/local/bin /usr/sbin /usr/bin /sbin /bin]: no such file or directory
```

I Tried setting different entry points, but none of them worked. Also, it's important that I don't use Dockerfile, I just set it in GCP run configuration

Comment: It depends on your build, but the Python executable is often named `python3` in Linux. Also, verify that Python is installed as part of your image.